# Where to get half of a pipe clamp

Tags: clamps

I was a little inattentive at a recent estate sale and as a result bought four halves of a pipe clamp hardware kit.  Specifically, I bought four of the stationary ends with the screw mechanism, as below.

[image: screw end]

What I need are another four of the sliding ends, pictured below.

[image: sliding end]

Aside from lucking into finding these at another estate sale or ebay, does anyone know where I might find just half of the pipe clamp hardware kit?

Comment: These things are so cheap I doubt anyone sells just half the clamp.

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda what I was thinking.

Comment: Ouch! If you don't mind the extra work drilling the pipe you could retain their full functionality by using a pin-locking system with shop-made sliding hardwood heads. For the pins I'd want to use tool steel (stronger for a smaller hole in the pipe, which weakens the pipe less) which unfortunately makes this less viable since it likely involves purchasing something, taking the cost closer to just buying new clamp heads.

Comment: Try pawn shops and the habitat restore or craigslist.

Answer (score 1):

> Aside from lucking into finding these at another estate sale or ebay, does anyone know where I might find just half of the pipe clamp hardware kit?

The clamp parts in your photos look like [the ones made by Bessey](http://www.besseytools.com/en/product_details.php?ASIMOID=000000030002b88f00040023&ASIMOID_SC=0000000100031d9e00050023). If those match the ones you bought, I'd [contact them](http://www.besseytools.com/en/contactus) to see if they'll sell you four of the tail pieces as spare parts.

Answer (score 0):

Home depot:  https://www.homedepot.com/p/LDR-Industries-3-4-in-x-3-ft-Galvanized-Steel-Schedule-40-Cut-Pipe-307-34X36/100571552

any size you want.  All you need to know is the length you want and the diameter of the pipe

Comment: The OP is not asking about pipe, they want to find just one half of the clamp that attaches to the pipe, as shown in the photos posted in the question.

Comment: oh i misundersood